# WSO2 APIM: Calling service APIs through cURL gives no response

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm using APIM 4.1.0. I am following [this](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/product-apis/publisher-apis/publisher-v2/publisher-v2/) and another tutorial to create an API through publisher service API. After generating the access token I use the below command but there is no response. No error code even. Are these URLs correct?

```
curl -k -H "Authorization: Bearer <access-token>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d @data.json https://127.0.0.1:9443/api/am/publisher/v2/apis
```

data.json file contains:

```
{
    "policies": [
        "Unlimited"
    ],
    "visibility": "PUBLIC",
    "visibleRoles": [],
    "visibleTenants": [],
    "cacheTimeout": 300,
    "endpointConfig": {
        "endpoint_type": "http",
        "sandbox_endpoints": {
            "url": "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/directions/"
        },
        "production_endpoints": {
            "url": "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/directions/"
        }
    },
    "subscriptionAvailability": null,
    "subscriptionAvailableTenants": [],
    "operations": [
        {
            "id": "postapiresource",
            "target": "string",
            "verb": "POST",
            "authType": "string",
            "throttlingPolicy": "Unlimited",
            "scopes": [
                "apim:api_view"
            ],
            "usedProductIds": [
                "string"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "responseCachingEnabled": false,
    "isDefaultVersion": true,
    "businessInformation": {
        "technicalOwner": "ApiCreator",
        "technicalOwnerEmail": "ApiCreator@pizzashack.com",
        "businessOwner": "ApiPublisher",
        "businessOwnerEmail": "ApiPublisher@pizzashack.com"
    },
    "transport": [
        "http",
        "https"
    ],
    "tags": [
        "phone",
        "multimedia",
        "mobile"
    ],
    "provider": "admin",
    "version": "Beta",
    "description": "Calculates directions between locations",
    "name": "GoogleDirectionsAPI",
    "context": "/googledirections"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use v3 version as follows.

```
curl -k -H "Authorization: Bearer <access-token>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d @data.json https://127.0.0.1:9443/api/am/publisher/v3/apis
```

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to upvote but **Yes, this works**. But also update your documentation with this - it's confusing.

Comment: Yes, doc update is on the way. :)